# Best way to have std::map where I can define what is returned if there is no key?

Tags: c++, c++11, visual-c++, std, stdmap

I am using a std::map to map some unsigned char machine values into human readable string types, e.g.:

```
std::map<unsigned char, std::string> DEVICE_TYPES = {
    { 0x00, "Validator" },
    { 0x03, "SMART Hopper" },
    { 0x06, "SMART Payout" },
    { 0x07, "NV11" },
};
```

I'd like to modify this so that if the key passed is not present, the map will return "Unknown".  I want the caller interface to stay the same (i.e. they just retrieve their string from the map using the [] operator).  What's the best way to do this?  I have C++11 on Windows 7 available.

Comment: Create a wrapper and implement the ````[]```` operator.

Comment: Good suggestion.  I'm not sure what the constructor would look like for using a list initializer like I have in the example however.  Any ideas on that?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You might create some wrapper with *operator[]* overloaded to provide the required behaviour:

```
class Wrapper {
public:
    using MapType = std::map<unsigned char, std::string>;

    Wrapper(std::initializer_list<MapType::value_type> init_list)
        : device_types(init_list)
    {}

    const std::string operator[](MapType::key_type key) const {
        const auto it = device_types.find(key);
        return (it == std::cend(device_types)) ? "Unknown" : it->second;
    }

private:
    const MapType device_types;
};
```

[**wandbox example**](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/bQQsA52ZflDyg4Cq)

Comment: Thanks, looks ideal.